# How do I create an async caching http client?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, asynchttpclient

Using the `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient-cache:4.1.3` library, I'm trying to work out how I can create an `asynchronous` `caching` http client?

I can create each individually, using their respective builders, but I can't find a way to have both.

#### e.g.

```
CloseableHttpClient client = CachingHttpClientBuilder.create()
    .setCacheConfig(cacheConfig())
    .build();
```

---

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient build = HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create()
    .build();
```

Por que no los dos?

**N.B.** I'm not tied to this version of the library - happy for solutions using the latest version.

**Related:**

- [How do I implement client side http caching like a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618619/how-do-i-implement-client-side-http-caching-like-a-browser)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new `CachingHttpAsyncClient` directly after you have built a `HttpAsyncClient`. For example:

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient asyncClient= HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create().build();

CachingHttpAsyncClient client = new CachingHttpAsyncClient(asyncClient, cacheConfig());
```

You can know more constructors from [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient-cache/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks @KeLi ! Any idea how I'd get this into a `AsyncRestTemplate` ?

Comment: @NickGrealy the best way seems to be a custom `ClientHttpRequestFactory` implementation based on `HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory` (which requires a `CloseableHttpAsyncClient` and therefore doesn't work as is)

Comment: @sfussenegger - want to post an answer? :)

Comment: @NickGrealy I've created a new question for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539146