# How do I create an AsyncRestTemplate in Spring with caching?

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpasyncclient, asyncresttemplate

I would like to create an [`AsyncRestTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html) which also has Http Caching enabled...

From what I've read, it seems as though I need to explicitly enable Http Caching by creating a AsyncHttpClient ([How do I create an async caching http client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623608/how-do-i-create-an-async-caching-http-client)
).

Unfortunately, I can't find any `RestTemplate` (or `ClientHttpRequestFactory`) constructors that allow me to utilise the [HttpAsyncClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/nio/client/HttpAsyncClient.html) interface (frustratingly the [HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory.html) takes a `CloseableHttpAsyncClient` abstract class??).

I'm currently contemplating writing a custom `ClientHttpRequestFactory` as an input to the `AsyncRestTemplate` - am I on the right path?

Related:

- docs.spring.io / [AsyncRestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html)
- docs.spring.io / [HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html)
- docs.spring.io / [HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory.html)
- hc.apache.org / [HttpAsyncClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/nio/client/HttpAsyncClient.html)
- [How do I create an async caching http client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623608/how-do-i-create-an-async-caching-http-client)

Comment: The answer in your other question gives you basically all you need. You pass the constructed client to a `HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory` which you pass to an `AsyncRestTemplate`. Not sure why you would need to create more/custom classes? Just 3 beans in your configuration. And obviously `RestTemplate` will not give you that as you should be looking at the `AsyncRestTemplate` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum, except `HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory` constructor takes a `CloseableHttpAsyncClient`, and not a `CachingHttpAsyncClient`... am I missing something?